# Word for someone who is willing to sacrifice others

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm trying to find a word to describe someone who is willing to sacrifice others to reach a goal for the greater good. I don't want to use **self sacrifice** as the character I'm trying to write about does not plan on giving themselves up, but I also don't think I can use **self interest** because this character cares about more than themselves.

Is there even a word for this? If not, is there a phrase that I might be able to use to describe this character's intentions?

Comment: "greater good" makes me think of **utilitaristic**

Answer (score 1):

From: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/utilitarian

**utilitarian**

adjective

2: Philosophy 
Relating to or adhering to the doctrine of utilitarianism.

‘a utilitarian theorist’

noun

*Philosophy*

An adherent of utilitarianism.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utilitarianism

Answer (score 0):

Cold-blooded? Ruthless? Callous? Machiavellian? 
There are several words you could use as descriptors or epithets, but I don't believe there's a single word that encapsulates that concept.